# Months difference between two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dates in the format `a = Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00')` and the other date is in same format `b = Timestamp('1993-09-01 00:00:00')`

So I'm trying to find number of months difference between these two, The way I did is

```
relativedelta(a,b).years * 12
```

Which gives the value `336`, but the actual difference is `346`. Please let me know where I went wrong help me correct it.

Comment: Your approach can return multiples of 12 only, you need to add the month of the split year from the time delta to it.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for the shortfall is because `relativedelta` is giving you the number of 'complete' years, i.e. from `1993-09-01` to `2021-09-1`, so you are missing the last ten months between `2021-09-01` and `2022-07-01`.  A simple modification to your current code is to add the months like this:

```
relativedelta(a,b).years * 12 + relativedelta(a,b).months
```

Which gives the correct result of `346` months.

Comment: No problem @beginnercoder.  Personally I prefer [Sreeram TP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7896849/sreeram-tp)'s answer as it doesn't require the use of `dateutil` in addition to `pandas` in the isolated case of your question.  If you're only using `dateutil` for this portion of the code I suggest using their solution to save using an additional library.

Answer (score 5):

You can round the date to Month with `to_period()` and then subtract the result

```
a = pd.Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00')
b = pd.Timestamp('1993-09-01 00:00:00')

months = a.to_period('M') - b.to_period('M')

print(months) # 346
```